# simplexml_load_string and a selfclosing enclosure tag

Tags: php, simplexml

Could anybody guide me how to extract a tag in an xml string. I use the following code to get the document and it works fine for title and description:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($text);
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){
  $title = $item->title;
}
```

But when it comes to this tag I don't know how to extract the url:

```
<enclosure url="http://www.blahblah.com/something.jpg" length="123" type="image/jpeg"/>
```

Any Ideas?